# Magnetic Multipole Tensor

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, tensor-calculus, multipole-expansion

When the electric scalar potential is expanded into spherical coordinates, one gets

\begin{align}
\phi (\vec r) =  \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^l \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}} Y_{lm} (\theta, \varphi) \frac{Q_{lm}}{r^{l+1}} 
\end{align}

with the electric multipole tensor

\begin{align}
Q_{lm} = \sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{2l+1}}\int r'^{l} Y^*_{lm} (\theta', \varphi') \rho(\vec r\,^\prime) d^3 r' \,.
\end{align}

This is simple and clear. But when the same is done for the magnetic vector potential, one gets

\begin{align}
\vec A(\vec r) = \mu_0 \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2l+1} \frac{1}{r^{l+1}}\sum_{m=-l}^l Y_{lm} (\theta, \varphi) \int  r'^l  Y^*_{lm} (\theta', \varphi') \vec j (\vec r\,^\prime)\, d^3 r' \, ,
\end{align}
and I don't see a way to define a magnetic multipole tensor like in the electric case, because now, in the integral, there is a vector, what makes the definition of a tensor of arbitrary rank quite awkward. So how can a magnetic multipole tensor be defined in this case?

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to use the [scalar magnetic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_scalar_potential). This method works for magnetostatical problems with permanent magnets (that is, without free currents).

In macroscopic electrodynamics and in the absence of free currents we have
$$\nabla \times \vec H = 0.$$
Therefore, given a simply connected domain, there exists a scalar potential $\psi$, such that:
$$ \vec H = - \nabla \psi. $$
(Formally, this is completely analogous to the existence of the scalar potential for the electrostatic field.)
From the relation $\vec B = \mu_0 (\vec H + \vec M)$ we get (note that $\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$ does *always* hold, even in macroscopic electrodynamics):
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec H = -\nabla \cdot \vec M. $$
Inserting the above relations one gets:
$$ \nabla \cdot \vec H = \nabla \cdot (-\nabla \psi) = -\nabla \cdot \vec M. $$
Rearranging gives:
$$ \Delta \psi = \nabla \cdot \vec M =: -\rho_m. $$
As this is formally equal to the Poisson equation from electrodynamics one can easily do a multipole expansion of $\psi$ in terms of multipoles of $\rho_m$ (the quantity $\rho_m$ is called bound magnetic charge). Outside of the permanent magnets the magnetization is zero, and therefore $\vec B$ can easily be computed from $\psi$ as:
$$ \vec B = -\mu_0 \nabla \psi. $$

Note, that all this does not imply there are magnetic monopoles! $\nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$ does hold all the time! $\rho_m$ is not a magnetic charge in the sense, that it is a source of $\vec B$, it is an artefact of handling some currents as bound and separating the flux density in magnetization and field strength.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason why you can't use the same method you used for the electric multipole expansion for magnetic multipole expansion.

The indices $l,m$ indicate the order of multipole expansion used in the approximation in those equations.

Since the $\vec A(\vec r)$ field you provided implies $\nabla \cdot \vec B(\vec r)=0$, i.e. there is no magnetic monopole, I would exploit the symmetry of magnetic dipole and use a power series of closed circuit loops

$$\vec A(\vec r)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\vec A_n(\vec r)$$

where

$$\vec A_n(\vec r)=\frac {\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^{n+1}} \oint_{v^{'}} {(r^{'})}^n P_n(cos\theta^{'})\vec J(\vec r^{'})d\tau^{'} $$

and $$cos\theta{'}= \hat{r} \cdot \hat r^{'}$$ $$r >> r^{'}$$

Since there is no known magnetic monopole in general - at least everywhere except possibly Stanford Univerity, then $\vec A_0(\vec r)=0$.

And $\vec A_1(\vec r)$ is the dipole used in magnetostatics, $\vec A_2(\vec r)$ is the quadrupole, etc.