# Spherical harmonics expansion: from scalars to tensors

Tags: field-theory, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

**Background:** A scalar field on the unit sphere can be [expanded in spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics), see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610907/226902). I am wondering if there is a related concept for vector fields and, in general, for any kind of tensor field. *Which is the basic idea/intuition behind the extension from scalar fields to tensor ones?*

This concept seems related to the [multipole expansion for vector fields](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/148354/226902), but it's not exactly the same concept. Moreover, I know that something called [vector spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics) exists and I am quite sure that this is the concept I have in mind for the case of vectors (see the example below and [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/706728/226902)). For the rank-2 case, I do not understand if the notion of [spherical tensor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770079/226902) provides a solution to the question.

**Question:** Given my doubts reported above, the definition of Wikipedia of [Vector spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_spherical_harmonics) seems quite arbitrary to me: I am not able to grasp the "rationale" behind it. **Which is the general concept we have to use when moving from scalar fields to tensor ones?**

**Example:** imagine having a field theory defined on the sphere (the base manifold is the unit sphere) and that we want to expand the energy-momentum tensor in series: we should use a proper basis of orthogonal "matrix" fields on the sphere. The same if we have a fluid flowing on the surface of a sphere: we need a set of vector fields that live on the sphere that are "complete" and "orthogonal". I expect that this set will be "countable" (like usual spherical harmonics for scalars) because the sphere is a compact manifold.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of spherical harmonics and even hyperspherical harmonics (in dimension d > 2) can be generalized for tensors of arbitrary rank. It is easiest for symmetric, transverse and traceless tensors. However, for some reason, the literature is really obscure. You will find a lot of answers in the paper [Symmetric Tensor Spherical Harmonics on the
N-Sphere and Their Application to the De Sitter Group SO(N,1)](https://inspirehep.net/literature/233580) by Higuchi and the references therein. Even though it is never stated there, all the results also hold for scalars and vectors (with certain qualifications, i.e. the scalars are not "traceless" - that does not make sense).

In the 2-dimensional case, (part of) the answer is simple: There are no symmetric transverse traceless tensor harmonics for tensors of rank r > 1. They only exist in 3 or more dimensions.